# Postgres 9.4 hangs during refreshing materialized view

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views, postgresql-9.4

I am considering the problems with materialized views in Postgres 9.4.
Sometimes query "refresh materialized view xxx" just hangs forever.

The only way I found is to completely restart postgres service. After restart execution takes seconds.

My view is not so complex it use about 10 tables.

I've executed `select * from pg_stat_activity where state = 'active'` and the only running query was refresh view.

This problem appears with CentOS operating system.

What should I look when this problems comes next time? locks? or something else?

Comment: Check for ungranted locks in `pg_locks` and check to see if the `pg_stat_activity` entry for the refresh has `waiting=t`. If that doesn't shed any light, make sure the debug symbols are installed for your PostgreSQL server and get a stack trace of the apparently-hung process. See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Linux/BSD .

Comment: You say that the "only way" is to restart PostgreSQL. What about `pg_cancel_backend`? Any reaction? How about `pg_terminate_backend`? Does it respond to that? What about control-C in `psql`?

Comment: @CraigRinger <code>pg_cancel_backend<code> cancels running query but when I run it again it hangs. The only way to prevent hanging is restart postgre service

Comment: Ok. Please get a stack trace if possible.

Comment: I upgraded to 10.3 recently and still see similar behavior.

Answer (score 7):

In my case the problem was in unclosed transaction.

There was a transaction in which my materialized view was queried. That transaction was never closed.

I've added a commit after query and it solves the issue.
Looks like postgre hold some locks on view until the transaction become closed.