# Postgres Refresh materialized view showing wait_event_type Extension for a 2+ hours

Tags: postgresql

A materialized view that I have, has its joins over 5 tables going over postgres_fdw to a remote DB.
This matview completed refresh in max 1 hour until yesterday.
However, today it just seems to be hung. A query on `pg_stat_activity` shows the session's `wait_event_type` is Extension from last hour.
The source code of this matview does not use any functions, just joins and that too on all remote tables ( no joins on local and remote tables).
I could not find much explanation on `Extension` wait_event.

```
   age       | wait_event_type | wait_event | state  |  backend_type
 |                                     query
--------------------+-------+-----------+------------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------+--------+---------- 
01:36:51.825826 | Extension       | Extension  | active | client backend
 | refresh materialized view
```

Could someone please explain what's happening? Appreciate any help troubleshooting this.
BTW I am on 12.4

## Solution:

Before I go ahead and post the solution, I followed below threads to see if it matches my case

[Postgres 9.4 hangs during refreshing materialized view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525453/postgres-9-4-hangs-during-refreshing-materialized-view)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/244150/postgres-wait-event-type-extension

But in my case, it was neither a function nor an open `idle in transaction` Session. I ended up analyzing my foreign tables using `ANALYZE` command and that was it!

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#WAIT-EVENT-EXTENSION-TABLE) says:

> | `Extension` Wait Event | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | `Extension` | Waiting in an extension. |

Since you are using foreign tables (I assume with postgres_fdw), it must be a remote query that is hanging.

Comment: yes, over postgres_fdw. `Waiting in an extension.` what does that mean? and why suddenly? I am just stumped and don't know what to do from here to get it working

Comment: Also, when I run the query outside of the `Refresh Materialized View` statement it works. Its the Refresh seems to be hanging.

Comment: You have to examine what goes on on the remote server(s). Examine if and why the queries are hanging there.

Answer (score 0):

Before I go ahead and post the solution, I followed below threads to see if it matches my case

Postgres 9.4 hangs during refreshing materialized view

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/244150/postgres-wait-event-type-extension

But in my case, it was neither a function nor an open idle in transaction Session. I ended up analyzing my foreign tables using ANALYZE command and that was it!